# iOS app freezes when tapping on notification action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, unusernotificationcenter

```
 -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 LSAddActivityViewController *addVC = [[LSAddActivityViewController alloc]init];
           addVC.leadID = LeadID;
           addVC.activityType = @"Notable Activity";
           [((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController) 
           pushViewController:addVC animated:YES];

});
completionHandler();
}
```

Above code executes when an Action is tapped on `UNUserNotificationCenter` local notification. `LSAddActivityViewController` is being launched with proper UI but app freezes, no touch is working anywhere on the app.

**NOTE -**  On orientation change UI is being re-drawn perfectly. `self.view.userInterationEnabled` is true always.

Comment: what is `LeadID`, how is it defined?

Comment: Apart from that, I cant see anything suspicious here. Probably something in your implementation of LSAddActivityViewController is messing up? Try to rip out all the functionality of it and then add back one by one, to see when the freeze happens again.

Comment: @bbjay There is no problem with the LeadID, Any suspicion with LSAddActivityViewController implementation ?

Comment: What happens if you push an empty UIViewController?

Comment: @bbjay Its hanging in case of empty UIViewController also.

Comment: do you also have the
`userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:` method implemented?

Comment: @bbjay no its not implemented.

Comment: @bbjay issue is fixed now, it was not related to anything that posted, some other shit. Thanks for your help.